# Proving electromagnetic wave equation is Lorentz invariant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

I am trying to prove that the electromagnetic wave equation is invariant under Lorentz transformation.

I need to show that
$$\frac{d^2U}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{d^2U}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2U}{dx'^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{d^2U}{dt'^2}$$
I currently have that $$\frac{d^2U}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{d^2U}{dt^2}=\gamma^2\frac{d^2U}{dx'^2}-\frac{\gamma^2v^2}{c^2}\frac{d^2U}{dx'^2}+\frac{\gamma^2v^2}{c^2}\frac{d^2U}{dt'^2}-\frac{\gamma^2}{c^2}\frac{d^2U}{dt'^2}$$
Assuming I did the derivatives (and second derivatives) properly, how do I reduce the right side to the left side? I believe the answer has something to do with the intrinsic relationship between v, c and $\gamma$.

If anyone could give me any pointers on condensing this (or if I messed up somewhere) or could point me to a resource that goes through this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

$$
\gamma^{2} - \frac{\gamma^{2} v^{2}}{c^{2}} 
= \gamma^{2} \left( 1 - \frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}} \right)
= \gamma^{2} \gamma^{-2} = 1
$$

this should solve your $\partial^{2} / \partial x^{'2}$ term.
The  $ \gamma^{2} v^{2}/c^{2}$ in front of $\partial^{2} / \partial t^{'2}$ doesn't have the correct dimensions. It is probably wrong. A factor of $\gamma^{2} v^{2} / c^{4}$ would give the correct answer though.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am unsure where I am missing the extra factor of $c^2$. For that term, I took that dU/dt = -$\gamma$ vdU/dx' + $\gamma$dU/dt'. Then taking $d^2U$/$dt^2$, I do not get another factor of $c^2$ out of it. I know that one factor of $c^2$ comes directly from the 'postulate', but where does the other $c^2$ come from when taking derivatives?

Comment: What about dU/dx?  =)